# Using turtle graphics and Circle drawing

Tags: math, automatic-ref-counting, turtle-graphics, pi

I'm new to coding and have started with a book called Think Python. In the following exercise - I've to use Turtle graphics to write functions for drawing a polygon and a circle. The solution is as follows:

```
#draw polygon
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
def Polygon(t,length,n):
    t = bob
    for i in range(n):
        bob.fd(length)
        bob.rt(360/n)

#draw circle
import math

def Circle(t,r):
    Circumference = 2*math.pi*r
    n=int(Circumference/3)+1
    length = Circumference/n
    Polygon(t,length,n)
```

But can someone explain to me what is happening at the last line `Polygon(t,length,n)`?  I don't understand what this is doing and why only if I include this line will the program run.

Answer (score 0):

The last line is a call to the `Polygon` function you defined earlier in the program (i.e. `def Polygon(t, length, n):`) which is what actually draws the polygon.  What you are doing is setting up the parameters for drawing a polygon and then calling the `Polygon` function with those parameters.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for your help!